# Displaying android's commands through code in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I have an android build of [codename one](http://www.codenameone.com)

Can i show the command menu through code in codename one for android build?

Right now , i need to click on the menu option to access the commands. Is there any code snippet through which I can make the commands appear on the screen (invoke the menu) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment since we don't support showing the native command menu and the command menu might not exist (think ActionBar on Android 3.x and newer).

However, showing the "lightweight" menu might work for some cases. Be warned that this is unsupported officially and this is in no way a recommendation to doing this!

You can call `Form.getMenuBar().showMenu()`, again this will work great in the simulator but on the actual devices your millage might vary in terms of device look/feel.